# What's the use of <?= ?> tags in PHP?

Tags: php

In some PHP scripts (actually it's the first time I've met this, in yii2 code), the `<?= ?>` tags are used. I'm not sure how these work, because their behavior is quite mysterious:

```
<?=
$a = 10;
echo $a . "\n";
```

This outputs, surprisingly, `1010`, and not `10`. I'm surprised that such special behavior finds no mention in the PHP manual also (or maybe I didn't look hard enough).

Comment: `<?= $someVar ?>` is basically equivalent to `<?php echo $someVar; ?>`. Google PHP echo short tags.

Comment: @aioobe This is not a short tag, strictly speaking. Using `<?` gives the expected output, but `<?=` doesn't.

Comment: I don't get your comment. I basically say the same thing as @NiranjanNRaju below.

Comment: @aioobe Sorry, I read "Google PHP echo short tags" as "Google PHP short tags". Hence the confusion. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<?=` this is the short tag in php.

Its equivalent to `<?php echo`

Your code is executed as

```
<?php
echo $a = 10;
echo $a . "\n";
```

`<?=` is replaced with `<?php echo`

So you are getting 10 twice in output.

Comment: Thanks! Will mark this as accepted answer when the site allows me to. :)

Comment: Glad It helped you:)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo 'whatever'; ?>
<? echo 'whatever'; ?>
```

and

```
<?='whatever';?>
```

are the same thing.

Just make sure you have `short_open_tag = On` in `php.ini`.

It basically saves you from typing as much.